# java.lang.LinkageError: loader drools/./.JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name:

Tags: java, drools, linkageerror

So I am getting the error below when using Drools to evaluate a set of rules [example below] using Stateful kieSessions. This error isn't consistent with it's appearance but it appeared enough times for it to be concerning. We are creating multiple sessions and calling `fireAllRules()` concurrenlty if that's useful.

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of org/drools/core/rule/JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "path/MY_SIMPLE_RULE"
    at "path/MY_SIMPLE_RULE"Eval1InvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at "path/MY_SIMPLE_RULE"Eval1Invoker.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.drools.core.rule.EvalCondition.isAllowed(EvalCondition.java:118) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakEvalNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakEvalNode.java:70) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakEvalNode.doNode(PhreakEvalNode.java:54) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:380) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:332) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:166) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:123) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:65) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.evaluateEagerList(DefaultAgenda.java:1004) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:961) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1292) ~[drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
```

Pseudo Rule

```
rule "MY_SIMPLE_RULE"
    lock-on-active true
    when
        eval($myAge) == 44);
        eval($myName == "Luffy");
    then
        $title.add("Captain"); 
end
```

Don't mind the correctness of the rule here because the rules that I am evaluating are reviewed and have been used for several years now. So somewhere down the line we use the kieSession to `fireAllRules()`.

Tried reproducing the error to no avail. So I am not sure what the exact issue is. The problem is the code works for majority of the rules and only broke for a few and those few don't even break all the times. It's sometimes they break, sometimes they do.